# Find aggregated sum of repetition spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Input :

Name1    Name2
arjun         deshwal
nikhil        choubey
anshul      pandyal
arjun         deshwal
arjun         deshwal
deshwal    arjun

Code used in scala

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                   .option("header", "true")
                   .load(FILE_PATH)
val result = df.groupBy("Name1", "Name2")
               .agg(count(lit(1))
               .alias("cnt"))
```

Getting Output :

nikhil    choubey      1
anshul    pandyal   1
deshwal    arjun    1
arjun      deshwal      3

Required Output :

nikhil      choubey   1
anshul    pandyal    1
deshwal   arjun      4

or

nikhil    choubey   1
anshul    pandyal   1
arjun     deshwal   4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach it using a set, which does not contain any order and therefore just compares on the content of the set:

```
scala> val data = Array(
 |     ("arjun",   "deshwal"),
 |     ("nikhil",  "choubey"),
 |     ("anshul",  "pandyal"),
 |     ("arjun",   "deshwal"),
 |     ("arjun",   "deshwal"),
 |     ("deshwal", "arjun")
 | )
data: Array[(String, String)] = Array((arjun,deshwal), (nikhil,choubey), (anshul,pandyal), (arjun,deshwal), (arjun,deshwal), (deshwal,arjun))

scala> val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
distData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:29

scala> val distDataSets = distData.map(tup => (Set(tup._1, tup._2), 1)).countByKey()
distDataSets: scala.collection.Map[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String],Long] = Map(Set(nikhil, choubey) -> 1, Set(arjun, deshwal) -> 4, Set(anshul, pandyal) -> 1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: cool! shows how important is it to think in terms of the right data model when trying to find a solution.